# QT permission member between classes

Tags: qt, permissions

I would like to send a member `parentWidget`, definited in a class function, to another class by a connection because I want to to add it in a list.
Unfornately I have got a error with this member permissions.

The respond error is:

> C2248: 'QGraphicsWidget::QGraphicsWidget': cannot access private member declared in class 'QGraphicsWidget'

So here is my function

```
void DiagramScene::insertWidget(DiagramItem::DiagramType diagramtype)
{
   QGraphicsWidget parentWidget;

   //some code

   connect(this,SIGNAL(sendToItemList(QGraphicsWidget)),diagramitem,SLOT(addToItemList(QGraphicsWidget)));
   emit this->sendToItemList(parentWidget);
}
```

and this is my slot:

```
void DiagramItem::addToItemList(QGraphicsWidget widget)
{
   QGraphicsWidget * newWidget;
   memmove(newWidget,&widget,sizeof(QGraphicsWidget));
   items.append(newWidget);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`QGraphicsWidget` inherits `QObject`, so it is uncopyable. The `addToItemList` function receives its argument by value, which leads to a copy attempt. One possible solution is to change the function's argument type to `QGraphicsWidget*` and create the object as `QGraphicsWidget *parentWidget = new QGraphicsWidget()`. This would also eliminate a very strange and incorrect use of `memmove` from your code.

Comment: At first I choosed `QGraphicsWidget` as pointer. But I want to delete it at the end because it add all the previous widgets in the list at each function call

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but as far as I know you can't copy `QGraphicsWidget` since it inherits from `QObject`. [(Can be read here)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator)

My suggestion:

```
void DiagramScene::insertWidget(DiagramItem::DiagramType diagramtype)
{
   QGraphicsWidget* parentWidget = new QGraphicsWidget();

   //some code

   connect(this,SIGNAL(sendToItemList(QGraphicsWidget)),diagramitem,SLOT(addToItemList(QGraphicsWidget)));
   emit this->sendToItemList(parentWidget);
}


void DiagramItem::addToItemList(QGraphicsWidget* widget)
{
   items.append(widget);
}
```